# ¿Cómo enviar el valor de los dos campos al controlador?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un script que recibe el valor de un campo de un formulario (Fecha) y en el controlador hago la consulta y con el resultado puedo mostrar si está disponible o no dicha fecha, funciona perfectamente, este es el código:

```
<script>
           
  let date;
  let url = "{{route('check.date')}}";

  $('#datepicker').change(function() {
      date = $(this).val();
      call_to_controller(date, url);
  });

  function call_to_controller(date, url) {

     $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: url,
      data: {"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
              url: url, date: date,
            },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        if (data) 
        {
          $("#date-response").html('La fecha está ocupada');
        } 
        else 
        {
          $("#date-response").html('');
        }
      },
      error: function (error) { 
        console.log(error); 
      }
                           
    });            
  };                         

</script>
```

Ahora necesito que la consulta se haga luego que el usuario selecione la `fecha` y la `hora` y no sé como hacerlo, hice este código, pero no sé con cual función debo agrupar las dos funciones `.change`para hacer el llamado a la función `call_to_controller`

```
<script>
           
  let date;
  let time;
  let url = "{{route('check.date')}}";

  $('#datepicker').change(function() {
      date = $(this).val();
  });

  $('#time').change(function() {
      time = $(this).val();
  });

  call_to_controller(date, time, url);

  function call_to_controller(date, time, url) {

    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: url,
      data: {"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
              date: date, time: time, url: url 
            },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        if (data) 
        {
          $("#date-response").html('La fecha está ocupada');
        } 
        else 
        {
          $("#date-response").html('');
        }
      },
      error: function (error) { 
        console.log(error); 
      }
                           
    });            
  };                         

</script>
```

Comment: Si lo he entendido bien... Yo creo que sería en ambos change, pero haciendo la comprobación de que ambos estén rellenados

Comment: Exacto, requiero que se detecte que ambos campos se hayan completado para poder hacer la consulta en el controlador, pero no tengo idea como hacerlo.

Comment: Ya lo tienes, es solo un if dentro de ambos `if ( $("#time").val()!=="" && $("#datepicker").val() !== "") call_to_controller()` jejeje

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias! eso era lo que necesitaba! ahora debo trabajar con un ciclo, cualquier cosa recurro otra vez a la comunidad. Nuevamente gracias!